# Установка Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver для AMD

Tags: android, android-studio, amd

При установке вылетает вот такая ошибка, хотя пишет, что всё установлено. Из-за этого не запускается эмулятор.[image: Ошибка]

Answer (score 0):

а ты в Windows features поставил галочки на Hyper-V ? еще в биосе надо включить virtualisation. У меня после этиъх операций установилось. Правда экран черный на AVD =( в оффлайне